# How do I call ExampleValidator to analyze split data sets?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tfx

Using:

```
Tensorflow version: 2.3.1
TFX version: 0.23.1
TFDV version: 0.24.0
TFMA version: 0.24.0
```

with an interactive context like so:

```
from tfx.orchestration.experimental.interactive.interactive_context import \
    InteractiveContext
context = InteractiveContext(
    pipeline_root=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "pipeline")
)
```

I created an ExampleGen using:

```
output = example_gen_pb2.Output(
             split_config=example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig(splits=[
                 example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name='train', hash_buckets=7),
                 example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name='test', hash_buckets=2),
                 example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name='eval', hash_buckets=1)
             ]))

example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input_base=os.path.join(base_dir, data_dir), output_config=output)
context.run(example_gen)
```

and later in the code, I tried evaluating the data using an ExampleValidator but it seems the ExampleValidator doesn't resolve the proper paths to the split data sets.

Creation of the validator works as expected:

```
example_validator = ExampleValidator(
             statistics=statistics_gen.outputs['statistics'],
             schema=schema_gen.outputs['schema'])
context.run(example_validator)
```

No warning or errors were had, but attempting to show the results, error on the paths not being correct:

```
context.show(example_validator.outputs['anomalies'])
```

> NotFoundError: /home/jovyan/pipeline/ExampleValidator/anomalies/16/anomalies.pbtxt; No such file or directory

The actual directory structure was like so:

```
.
└── anomalies
    └── 16
        ├── eval
        │   └── anomalies.pbtxt
        ├── test
        │   └── anomalies.pbtxt
        └── train
            └── anomalies.pbtxt

5 directories, 3 files
```

but the code seemed to expect:

```
└── anomalies
    └── 16
        └── anomalies.pbtxt
```

How do I call ExampleValidator to analyze split data sets?

Comment: Note that the Keras Component example [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/tutorials/tfx/components_keras.ipynb) suffers the same issue so I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/2582).

Comment: The issue is resolved by upgrading tfx to 0.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Lorin S., for sharing the solution reference. For the benefit of community I am providing solution here (answer section) given by 1025KB in [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/2582#issuecomment-700865479).

> Added split in TFX 0.23 version, but Colab is not updated in 0.23.
> Colab is fixed in 0.24 [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/b01482442891a49a1487c67047e85ab971717b75/tfx/orchestration/experimental/interactive/standard_visualizations.py#L55)

Issue was resolved by upgrading tfx to 0.24